# How to set a custom icon to an IOS push notification?

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification

I'm currently adding notifications to my Flutter app for IOS, I wanted to add something similar to a `largeIcon` on Android, so far I didn't find a way to do that, only adding an image which is not a solution since I only want an icon at the right even if the user expands the notification (the image will expand too in this case which is undesirable for my use case).

As an alternative, I was wondering if I could change the notification app icon. As far as I looked around, this is not possible either, but at the same time I saw this image of notifications (the first one and the last one) that have a custom image and the app icon is smaller.

How can I do this in my app? I couldn't find any way in the documentation on how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with communication notifications. From [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/notifications/):

> The system automatically displays a large version of your app icon at
> the leading edge of each notification; in a communication
> notification, the system displays the sender’s contact image — or
> avatar — badged with a small version of your icon.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/implementing_communication_notifications) is the documentation on how to implement communication notifications in your app.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not a huge fan of just pointing to a documentation as it is not really helpful for people that are not familiar with the matter (including myself). So here is a full functional example for Flutter. This for sure will work for other iOS-Apps as well. It follows the the documentation provided by Apple [Implementing communication notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/implementing_communication_notifications) and adds an actual ready to run case. Make sure to adjust your payload / message to your needs. The example payload is for demonstration but can be used in conjunction with the commented payload snippet.

### Setup and prepare you project

Before you can start you have to do some preparation work to get everything up and running. I assume you already have a project otherwise create one using `flutter create`.

#### Xcode Capabilities

Select "Runner" within your Targets and add the Communication Notification Capability by hitting `+ Capability`. This is needed for displaying communication notifications.
[image: Add Communication Notifications Capabilities]

#### Adjustments to Info.plist

Go to `ios\Runner\Info.plist` and add the key `NSUserActivityTypes` with the `INSendMessageIntent` value. This allows us to use the SendMessageIntent as we basically send ourselves a message. Note: I removed all other entries just to avoid cluttering my answer. Append the key and its array to your Info.plist and do not delete anything else!

**Info.plist**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>INSendMessageIntent</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

### Notification Service Extension

1. In Xcode select the "Runner"-Project
2. Go to "File" => "New" => "Target"
3. Search for Notification Service Extension and hit 'Next'
4. Add a package name for your extension and hit 'Finish'

Now we should have a working project with a `NotificationService.swift` code file that represents our extension. This is where we now can adjust the notification we receive.

I've dumped a ready to run code sample below with all necessary comments. Follow the comments to get a better understanding.

**NotificationService.swift**

```swift
import UserNotifications
import Intents

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    /// This is called when a notification is received.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - request: The notification request.
    ///   - contentHandler: The callback that needs to be called when the notification is ready to be displayed.
    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler


        // the OS already did some work for us so we do make a work copy. If something does not go the way we expect or we run in a timeout we still have an attempt that can be displayed.
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        // unwrapping makes the compiler happy
        if(bestAttemptContent == nil) {
            return;
        }

        // this is the FCM / APNS payload defined by the server / caller. 
        // Its the custom '"data"' object you provide in the FCM json.
        // adjust it to your needs. This is just an example.
        let payload: [AnyHashable : Any] = bestAttemptContent!.userInfo

        // we assume that we get a type in the payload
        // either remove this line or add a type to your payload
        let type: String? = payload["type"] as? String

        // this is set by the server to indicate that this is a chat message
        if(type == "chat") {
            _handleChatMessage(payload: payload)

            return;
        }

        // if we do not know the type we just pass the notification through
        // this is the case when we get a plain FCM / APNS notification
        if let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    /// Handles a chat message notification. It tries to display it as a communication notification.
    /// - Parameter payload: The FCM / APNS payload, defined by the server / caller.
    func _handleChatMessage(payload: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        guard let content = bestAttemptContent else {
            return
        }

        guard let contentHandler = contentHandler else {
            return
        }

        // add your custom logic here. Read the payload information and act accordingly.
        // all following code assumes you provide this information in the payload.

        // let chatRoomName: String? = payload["chatRoomName"] as? String

        // guard let chatRoomName: String = chatRoomName, !chatRoomName.isEmpty else {
        //     return
        // }

        let chatRoomName: String = "My Custom Room" // this can be a senders name or the name of a channel or group

        let senderId: String = "f91840a2-a1bd-4d7a-a7ea-b4c08f7292e0" // use whatever value you have from your backend

        let senderDisplayName: String = "Sender A"

        let senderThumbnail: String = "https://picsum.photos/300"

        guard let senderThumbnailUrl: URL = URL(string: senderThumbnail) else {
            return
        }

        let senderThumbnailFileName: String = senderThumbnailUrl.lastPathComponent // we grab the last part in the hope it contains the actual filename (any-picture.jpg)

        guard let senderThumbnailImageData: Data = try? Data(contentsOf: senderThumbnailUrl),
            let senderThumbnailImageFileUrl: URL = try? downloadAttachment(data: senderThumbnailImageData, fileName: senderThumbnailFileName),
            let senderThumbnailImageFileData: Data = try? Data(contentsOf: senderThumbnailImageFileUrl) else {

            return
        }

        // example for adding attachments. Will be displayed by the communication notification.
        var attachments: [UNNotificationAttachment] = [];

        // Note: TODO -> Make sure that it has a file extension. Otherwise the creation of an attachment will fail and return nil.
        let link: String? = "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/368/536/354.jpg?hmac=2b0UU6Y-8XxkiRBhatgBJ-ni3aWJ5CcVVENpX-mEiIA" // payload["link"] as? String

        if let link = link, !link.isEmpty {
            let url = URL(string: link)
            let fileName = url!.lastPathComponent // same here => we hope it contains a proper file extension.

            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

            if(imageData != nil) {
                let attachment = createNotificationAttachment(identifier: "media", fileName: fileName, data: imageData!, options: nil)

                if attachment != nil {
                    attachments.append(attachment!)
                }
            }
        }

        // Add a preview to the notification.
        // Maybe the sender attached a picture or a video.
        // Handle attachments here before converting it to a communication notification
        // as I had issues when trying adding attachments afterwards.
        // Note: Those can be reused in the Notification Content Extension
        content.attachments = attachments

        // profile picture that will be displayed in the notification (left side)
        let senderAvatar: INImage = INImage(imageData: senderThumbnailImageFileData)

        var personNameComponents = PersonNameComponents()
        personNameComponents.nickname = senderDisplayName

        // the person that sent the message
        // we need that as it is used by the OS trying to identify/match the sender with a contact
        // Setting ".unknown" as type will prevent the OS from trying to match the sender with a contact
        // as here this is an internal identifier and not a phone number or email
        let senderPerson = INPerson(
                                    personHandle: INPersonHandle(
                                                    value: senderId,
                                                    type: .unknown
                                                ),
                                    nameComponents: personNameComponents,
                                    displayName: senderDisplayName,
                                    image: senderAvatar,
                                    contactIdentifier: nil,
                                    customIdentifier: nil,
                                    isMe: false, // this makes the OS recognize this as a sender
                                    suggestionType: .none
                                )

        // this is just a dummy person that will be used as the recipient
        let selfPerson = INPerson(
                                    personHandle: INPersonHandle(
                                                    value: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", // no need to set a real value here
                                                    type: .unknown
                                                ),
                                    nameComponents: nil,
                                    displayName: nil,
                                    image: nil,
                                    contactIdentifier: nil,
                                    customIdentifier: nil,
                                    isMe: true, // this makes the OS recognize this as "US"
                                    suggestionType: .none
                                )

        // the actual message. We use the OS to send us ourselves a message.
        let incomingMessagingIntent = INSendMessageIntent(
                                            recipients: [selfPerson],
                                            outgoingMessageType: .outgoingMessageText, // This marks the message as outgoing
                                            content: content.body, // this will replace the content.body
                                            speakableGroupName: nil,
                                            conversationIdentifier: chatRoomName, // this will be used as the conversation title
                                            serviceName: nil,
                                            sender: senderPerson, // this marks the message sender as the person we defined above
                                            attachments: []
                                    )

        incomingMessagingIntent.setImage(senderAvatar, forParameterNamed: \.sender)

        let interaction = INInteraction(intent: incomingMessagingIntent, response: nil)

        interaction.direction = .incoming

        do {
            // we now update / patch / convert our attempt to a communication notification.
            bestAttemptContent = try content.updating(from: incomingMessagingIntent) as? UNMutableNotificationContent

            // everything went alright, we are ready to display our notification.
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent!)
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
    }

    /// Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    /// Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    /// Shorthand for creating a notification attachment.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - identifier: Unique identifier for the attachment. So it can be referenced within a Notification Content extension for example.
    ///   - fileName: The name of the file. This is the name that will be used to store the name on disk.
    ///   - data: A Data object based on the remote url.
    ///   - options: A dictionary of options. See Apple's documentation for more information.
    /// - Returns: A UNNotificationAttachment object.
    func createNotificationAttachment(identifier: String, fileName: String, data: Data, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        do {
           if let fileURL: URL = downloadAttachment(data: data, fileName: fileName) {
                let attachment: UNNotificationAttachment = try UNNotificationAttachment.init(identifier: identifier, url: fileURL, options: options)

                return attachment
            }

            return nil
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error)")
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Downloads a file from a remote url and stores it in a temporary folder.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - data: A Data object based on the remote url.
    ///   - fileName: The name of the file. This is the name that will be used to store the name on disk.
    /// - Returns: A URL object pointing to the temporary file on the phone. This can be used by a Notification Content extension for example.
    func downloadAttachment(data: Data, fileName: String) -> URL? {
        // Create a temporary file URL to write the file data to
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let tmpSubFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let tmpSubFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(tmpSubFolderName, isDirectory: true)

        do {
            // prepare temp subfolder
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: tmpSubFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL: URL = tmpSubFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

            // Save the image data to the local file URL
            try data.write(to: fileURL)

            return fileURL
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error)")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

### Additional things to consider

I've added additional notes and things to consider as solely displaying the message is often not enough and there are other pitfalls to consider. I'm sure they will save you some time especially the part that you can't reliable use the silent notifications on iOS (the point why we have to use a Notification Service Extension).

#### FCM Payload / Silent Push

Make sure that you do use an actual alert for iOS / APNS as silent notifications will not be processed after a certain inactivity time of your app. On Flutter it will work to some degree and then stops working. This is by design but for newcomers this is a huge pitfall, as you will not recognise it until users complain that they do not receive notifications after a certain time. You can use the playground to generate a token and testing your implementation when using FCM: [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

**Example Payload for FCM**

```json
{
  "message": {
    "token": "TOKEN retrieved from Google OAuth Playground",
    "apns": {
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "alert": {
            "title": "Sender A",
            "body": "Hello Service Extension"
          },
          "mutable-content": 1,
          "content-available": 1,
          "sound": "default"
        }
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "note": "This is an example payload!",
      "type": "chat",
      "chatRoomName": "My Custom Room",
      "senderId": "f91840a2-a1bd-4d7a-a7ea-b4c08f7292e0",
      "senderDisplayName": "Sender A",
      "senderThumbnail": "https://picsum.photos/300",
      "link": "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/368/536/354.jpg?hmac=2b0UU6Y-8XxkiRBhatgBJ-ni3aWJ5CcVVENpX-mEiIA"
    }
  }
}
```

You still can use silent notifications on Android as they will trigger your app even in terminated state. This way you can use Flutter plugins on Android and disable them when Platform is iOS. Or you can use a combination and turn on/off the foreground visualisation based on your cases.

#### Use of Plugins

If you do use a plugin like [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) in your Flutter App be aware that the extension is called when "mutable-content" is set to 1. So if you see your notification twice and even in different layouts then you have either to disable the presentation while in foreground or to waive calls to flutter_local_notifications when Platform is iOS and let your extension handle the visualisation.

**Disabling Notification in Foreground**

```dart
 if (Platform.isIOS) {
        // disable foreground notifications to make sure the app extension handles them
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
          alert: false,
          badge: false,
          sound: false,
        );
      }
```

#### iOS Push Notification Attachments

With the default implementation only the first attachment is displayed as a thumbnail in your push notification. Keep that in mind. If you need a more specific behaviour use "Rich Notifications" aka Notification Content Extension.

#### Your extension will be called for all notifications!

Keep also in mind that your extension will be called for all notifications your app will receive. Use a Category Identifier (request.content.categoryIdentifier) in your extension for example to filter or submit a type (as I did) in the payload.

### Example

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful; did you also find any limitation applying custom body constructing INSendMessageIntent(..., content: here) ? 
Always overridden by original payload body on my side

Comment: @nekflamm maybe my Example Payload is misleading. If so I will change that. Can you test it without setting a title and a body in the apns payload but just use the payload ("data"): let payload: [AnyHashable : Any] = bestAttemptContent!.userInfo? So INSendMessageIntent content: payload["message"]. Can you give me a feedback if that did the trick? I just checked my backend and I do set it they way in my post but maybe Apple did change something? Also what is in your body? Plain text? I only send plain text including emojis and that worked fine so far.

Comment: @nekflamm also make sure that you really handle everything in your custom function. If your extension calls contentHandler(bestAttemptContent) then everything done before will be "thrown" away. Also ensure that you do not encounter any exception. Everything that leads to an error will cause the contentHandler to get called. Finally you can't ignore any incoming message. If so iOS will take care of it. There is an entitlement only granted to a very few apps (because reasons...).

Comment: @nekflamm Sorry for spamming you but also make sure that if you have images to download that they do load fast. I mean really fast under a second or two. Otherwise you risk that iOS will take over and will handle the push notification for you resulting in contentHandler(bestAttemptContent) to get called. Which then also appears that iOS seems like to override your content.body.

Comment: that's a lot thanks buddy! your last loading advice is very important I didn't know. regarding the rest, yes we use only text or emoji as you do and I'll test your trick with title/body "missing" but that's quite dangerous I guess if any fallback in the contentHandler part...

Comment: @nekflamm I agree with you its just for you to test. Also check with different values in the APNS payload and in the data payload. Maybe you can spot a difference. When the one from APNS payload is shown then you know that an error triggered the default behavior. Saddly its a painful topic to debug. PS: May users are reporting everthing is working fine. So I guess my code here is still OK.

Comment: @nekflamm I also just checked the App Store side. Maybe the culprit is there. Check if under "Identifiers" your Push-Notification-Extension is added with a bundleId. Like "app.myapp.pushnotification" <- Name that you have in xCode. Ensure that your main app and your extension is in the same App Group. https://pasteboard.co/TIybEHFj10RL.png . Let me know if something did the trick. I then will for sure update my post.