# How to set a custom icon to an Android / IOS push notification in expo react native app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

please check the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71196442/how-to-set-a-custom-icon-to-an-ios-push-notification) for more information as I want to implement exactly that in Expo react native

I have tried using the expo-notification package and also the Notifee package but can't seem to find a way to add this functionality

[push notification with custom icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QzrH.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented with Notifee/react-native package it worked for both bare expo and react native cli projects, for a bare expo project after installing notifee by following their documentation [here](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/installation), then add the required capability to the app through app.json file by

```
 "ios": {
       "entitlements": {
          "com.apple.developer.usernotifications.communication": true
       },
      "infoPlist": {
          "UIBackgroundModes": ["location", "fetch", "remote-notification"],
      "NSUserActivityTypes": ["INSendMessageIntent"]
    },
   }
```

this adds communication notification capability for ios  and also add INSendMessageIntent to the NSUserActivityTypes in info.plist

then using the Notifee package to display the notification by:

```
 await notifee.displayNotification({
  title: "Some title",
  body: "Notification Body",
  ios: {
    foregroundPresentationOptions: {
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
      banner: true,
      list: true,
    },
    categoryId: 'messageID',
    communicationInfo: {
      conversationId: "123",
      sender: {
        id: "456",
        avatar: "Avatar-url",
        displayName: "John Doe",
      },
    },
  }
})
```